# How does Oracle Proc find C header files?

Tags: c, oracle, include

I have a `#include <stdio.h>` in one of my `*.pc` files.
And this `stdio.h` includes `libio.h`.

I'm getting a syntax error on the `libio.h`.

I wonder how Oracle proc knows where to find those `stdio.h` and `libio.h` files.

Environment?
Some standard paths?

Answer (score 1):

Found in $ORACLE_HOME/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg